# How to check if someone has liked a post so they can't like it more than once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm making a site where you can make posts and like them. I've added a like button and it counts and saves the amount of likes on each post in an array. However, users can like the post as many times as they like. How can I make it so it compares the user id in the array with the id of the user so it will only allow them to like it once.

this is the like array inside my post model

```
likes: [{
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    }       
}]
```

this is the actual button and what listens for the click

```
<div>
    <button class = "likesButton" id = "{{this._id}}" href = "/likes/{{this._id}}" 
        class="btn btn-dark">likes
    </button>
    <span> {{ this.likes.length }} </span>
</div>

{{/each}}
{{/if}}

<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.js"
    integrity = "sha256-bd8XIKzrtyJ1O5Sh3Xp3GiuMIzWC42ZekvrMMD4GxRg=" crossorigin = "anonymous">
</script>

<script>
    const likesButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.likesButton');

    likesButtons.forEach( likeButton => {

        likeButton.addEventListener('click', ( ) => {

            axios.post(`/likes/${likeButton.id}`);
            location.reload();
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is the app.post in my server.js

```
app.post('/likes/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        //console.log(req.params.id)
        const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
        post.likes.unshift({ user: req.user.id });

        await post.save();
        res.redirect('/cogfeed');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to check for existence within an array.